# How do I get just the product additional information in the view.phtml template?

Tags: product, product-attribute, products

Ho do I do this? I tried this bit of code from the attributes.phtml but it doesn;t output anything.

```
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>ewfawef
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label secondary"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
    <?php endif;?>
```

All I want to display is the "additional attributes" table, no description or anything else.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is related to Magento 1.9.0.1, RWD theme. 
1- First of all make sure the following block is available in catalog.xml file.

> app/design/frontend/[your_package]/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
        <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional"  template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

2 - Then make sure following code is available in view.phtml file.

> app/design/frontend/[your_package]/default/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

3 - Next make sure the product attribute you want viewing on Product Page is set as:

> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end = **Yes**

4 - After that clear cache and refresh product detail page.